# "list indices must be integers, not str' error when using strptime function

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a list of dates, written as strings, called depart_date

```
depart_date = ['3/1/2012', '3/4/2012', '3/11/2012']
```

etc.

I'd like to convert them to date objects. This is what I have:

```
for i in depart_date:
    dep_date = datetime.strptime(depart_date[i], '%m/%d/%Y')
```

and it gives me the TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str.
I'm not sure why I'm getting this error because I thought the strptime function was supposed to convert strings into date objects.

Any help??

Comment: `i` is the value, not the index, so replace `depart_date[i]` with `i`, and it will probably be worthwhile to rename `i` to `cur_date` or something

Comment: I have edited your question to include the language tag based on the syntax in the question. If this is the incorrect language, please update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `.Length`

```
for i in depart_date.Length:
    dep_date = datetime.strptime(depart_date[i], '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Alternative:

```
for i in depart_date:
    dep_date = datetime.strptime(i, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with javascript, but i just know it has to be something along the lines of that. I think `i` has to be an enumerated value directly out of the variable you pass after `in`. That's why i posted the second alternative. It seems similar to the C# `foreach`, and in that case, you would have to do it as my second example.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is python, not javascript. Javascript notation is [`for( variable in object ) { }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)